# Redis won't serialize my complex object?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack.redis

I have this simple class:

```
 public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int[] friends = new int[100];
    }
```

Then I create Ienumerable  like this :

```
 IEnumerable<Person> lstPerson = ParallelEnumerable.Range(a, b).Select(f => new Person
            {
                Id = ...,
                Name =...,
                Age = ...,
                friends = ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, 100).ToArray()
            });
```

But running `Monitor`  , you can see the the array is **not** serialized :

[image]

Related info :

this is how I actually insert to Redis :

```
   using (IRedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient(host))
            {
                IRedisTypedClient<Person> phones = redisClient.As<Person>();
                foreach (var element in lstPerson)
                {
                      phones.SetEntry("urn:user>" + element.Id, element);
                }
            }
```

**Question :**

What am I doing wrong ? why the array is not serialized and HOw can I make it to be included ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `friends` is a field, not a property.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
  //public int[] friends = new int[100];
    public int[] Friends {get; set; }
}
```

since you fill it later with a `ToArray()` you don't really need to initialize it. When you still want to, use a constructor or write the long form of the property.

Comment: That's what happens when you 12 hours working .... Thanks . Stupid mistake...indeed , property should be used :-)